# Url Issue while sending mail in classic asp

Tags: html, email, asp-classic

I have an classic asp application which is trying to send a mail on a particular event and this is how the code goes:

```
var vStSMTPServer = "http://127.0.0.1"
var vObCDOMsg = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message"); 
var vObCDOConf = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration");
var vObCDOFlds = vObCDOConf.Fields;

// Set the CDOSYS configuration fields to use port 25 on the SMTP server.
//With vObCDOFlds



//--these information are being retrieved from db:

vObCDOMsg.Configuration = vObCDOConf;
vObCDOMsg.To      = email;      
vObCDOMsg.From    = frmAddress; 
vObCDOMsg.Subject = subject ;               
vObCDOMsg.Bcc     = bcc

//--this is the body

var body= 
body = <link href='http://www.es.com/longh/pages/eventsStyle.css' rel='stylesheet'><style type='text/css'>td{font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;font-size: 9pt;line-height: 14px;color: #313104;}</style></head><body><table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'><tr><td><br /></td></tr><tr><td align='center'><table width='600' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'><tr><td colspan='3' bgcolor='#CBBE92'></td></tr><tr><td rowspan='2' bgcolor='#CBBE92'></td><td><table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'><tr><td colspan='2' width='100%' height='50'><table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'><tr><td width='100%' height='33'>&nbsp;</td><td rowspan='2' width='153'><img src='http://www.es.com/longh/images/EStit2.gif' width='153' height='50' border='0' alt=''></td></tr><tr><td width='100%' height='20' bgcolor='#000000' colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td width='140' height='100' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#000000'><img src='http://www.es.com/longh/images/logoHostsmall2.gif' width='179'height='127' border='0' alt=''></td><td width='460' bgcolor='#000000'><img src='http://www.es.com/longh/images/GSQ12.jpg' width='460' height='127' border='0' alt=''></td></tr><tr><td width='140' bgcolor='#000000'>&nbsp;</td><td bgcolor='#000000' height='18'><img src='http://www.es.com/longh/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='18' border='0' alt=''></td></tr></table></td><td rowspan='2' bgcolor='#CBBE92'></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td align='center'><table width='776' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'><tr><td><table width='560' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'><tr><td><br />Dear " + salutation + "<h5>Marriott Events Preorder</h5></td></tr><tr><td style='text-align: justify;'>We are delighted that you will attend the <font color='#000000'>" + eventname + "</font>on <font color='#000000'>" + eventdate + "</font>.<br />&nbsp;<br />We would like to provide you with the opportunity to make beverage and special dietary arrangements prior to the event, and have created an online pre-order facility for your convenience.<br />&nbsp;<br /></td></tr><tr><td>You will need to use the <b>Username:</b> <font color='red'>" + username + "</font> and the <b>Password:</b> <font color='red'>" + password + "</font> to gain access.<br />&nbsp;<br />Please ensure that you complete your pre-order by <font color='#000000'>" + deadline + "</font>.<br />&nbsp;<br /><a href='http://www.es.com/longh/?username=" + username + "' style='text-decoration: underline;'>Please click here to Sign In.</a><br />&nbsp;<br /><i>In case the above link does not work you can copy this url( <b>www.es.com/longh/?username=" + username +"</b>) and paste in your browser</i><br />&nbsp;<br />Feel free to contact Private Hospitality  on 111111xxxxxx22 / 8122 if you have any questions.<br />&nbsp;<br />We are looking forward to seeing you,<br />&nbsp;<br />Kind Regards,<br />&nbsp;<br />Events Team<br /><b>Grosvenor House</b><br />&nbsp;<br /></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body>";
 vObCDOMsg.AutoGenerateTextBody =false;
                vObCDOMsg.HTMLBody=body;
```

After the mail is getting send, when the receiver clicks on the above link the url is getting redesigned and coming something like this:

```
<a href="http://zixvpm.infosecpartners.co.uk/?a=2541&amp;m=&amp;n=&amp;s=a800000055267a&amp;u=http%3a%2f%2fwww.eventsummary.com%2flongh%2f%3fusername%3dhtest33%26utm_source%3d%26utm_medium%3demail%26utm_campaign%3dunspecified&amp;t=&amp;e=subratkumar.parichha%40gmail.com&amp;h=d6c5af2e" style="text-decoration:underline" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="***https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=http://zixvpm.infosecpartners.co.uk/?a%3D2541%26m%3D%26n%3D%26s%3Da800000055267a%26u%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.eventsummary.com%252flongh%252f%253fusername%253dhtest33%2526utm_source%253d%2526utm_medium%253demail%2526utm_campaign%253dunspecified%26t%3D%26e%3Dsubratkumar.parichha%2540gmail.com%26h%3Dd6c5af2e&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1463542862806000&amp;usg=AFQjCNFk6t5OtTcmeIkJzpRDeSGlFTddSw"***>Please click here to Sign In.</a>
```

For 2 out of 10 users this section

```
dunspecified%26t%3D%26e%3DMadeleine.Montgomery%2540sonyatv.com%
```

has some extra characters getting appended to the link and it is not working.
something like this:

```
dunspecified%26t%3D%26e%3Mad%0d%0a%20%0d%0a%20eleine.Montgomery%40sonyatv.com%
```

Here are the urls having issue:
http://zixvpm.infosecpartners.co.uk/?a=2541&m=&n=&s=a400000019ae8f&u=http%3a%2f%2fwww.es.com%2flongh%2f%3fusername%3dontgomery42%26utm_source%3d%26utm_medium%3demail%26utm_campaign%3dunspecified&t=&e=Mad%0d%0a%20%0d%0a%20eleine.Montgomery%40sonyatv.com&h=b886b5d2

http://zixvpm.infosecpartners.co.uk/?a=2541&m=&n=&s=ba00000134a7c3&u=http%3a%2f%2fwww.es.com%2flongh%2f%3fusername%3deters82%26utm_source%3d%26utm_medium%3demail%26utm_campaign%3dunspecified&t=&e=karolin.peters%254!0nkf.ch&h=949d75bf

http://zixvpm.infosecpartners.co.uk/?a=2541&m=&n=&s=a60000000bf20e&u=http%3a%2f%2fwww.es.com%2flongh%2f%3fusername%3dargue32%26utm_source%3d%26utm_medium%3demail%26utm_campaign%3dunspecified&t=&e=vicki.dargue%40pla!cesforpeople.co.uk&h=8b1c26e4

Can some one share some thoughts on how this is behaving like this?

Comment: Can we see the code for how `body` is generated? Is the problem happening in only specific email clients? It may help if you could provide the exact problem URL for the 2 out of 10 users, rather than just something like it.

Comment: Do you `Server.UrlEncode()` the link before adding it to the `HTMLBody`?

Comment: Also is this a typo? - `<br />a href=` the `<a>` tag isn't correctly formed missing `<` bracket.

Comment: @John, I have updated all the information in the question. Also all those email clients having issue mentioend.

Comment: @Lankymart, I'll try with Server.UrlEncode() and to the missing < bracket here is no error with the syntax. I have removed certain texts, so that the code will appear as pure text and not as html.

Comment: Right, may be I'm not understanding you but the link in your `body` variable points to http://www.es.com/ but the links you mention are all coming from http://zixvpm.infosecpartners.co.uk/, are you saying they are being changed when sent to a recipient?

Comment: @Lankymart, you are right. es.com is still there in he final link. but it is also getting appended with " zixvpm.infosecpartners.co.uk" which I think might be the smtp server. In addition to this also the receiver mail id is also appended to the url. And if you see closely the issue is mostly occuring with the extra spaces adding to this receiver mail id.

Comment: Sounds to me like it's being added by this infosecpartners.co.uk, do they provide you with a product a proxy or something? I would be speaking to them to find out how to stop the mail being manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

There are limits on maximum recommended line lengths sent in emails, some email clients add spaces and other characters if you go over these limits, I've had this happen in emails before when sending via ASP.

Try splitting the long link onto a few lines, with a line break at each space so before style= and target= etc, and see if that helps.

```
link ="<a href='long stuff here' " & vbCrLf _
& "style='some style' " & vbCrLf _
& "target='some target'> " & vbCrLf
```

instead of

```
link = "<a href='long stuff here' style='some style' target='some target'>"
```

Ralph

Comment: Not sure that is the issue the `href` is being manipulated at the point of sending the message to the SMTP server, looks to be some kind of security product /' proxy / firewall issue.

Comment: Ah, I thought the href was only incorrect when it was viewed **in** the email. Apologies.